# Emulate tablet with 5 icons per row in Eclipse

Tags: android, emulation

I would like to test a widget on a Galaxy note. I have searched but not found an emulator for this device. Is there a way to emulate it with AVD manager? What I would like to emulate basically is the 5 icons per row functionality.

If there is no way, is there a device emulator available that has 5 icons per row?

Thanks

Comment: That's a good one, I did make a AVM with a 1280x800 resolution, but didn't even think about the rows. I'd have to look into it, but isn't that a feature of the skin that Samsung put on it? (whatsitcalled, touchwiz )

Comment: Just a 'note' : the note seems to have a 285dpi, so don't forget to change that in your AVM.

Comment: density 320 according to http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/13711-samsung-galaxy-note-emulator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that 5 icons per row is not supported by emulator - it is feature of Samsung's TouchWiz specially for 'note'. So you can't check your feature on emulator